# Right to left theme: Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation?

Tags: 8

I am developing multilingual site (English and Arabic) in Drupal 8. I want to use bootstrap or zurb foundation, which out of these is good for developing Right to left theme. Site will mainly work in Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

"Foundation was built to support right-to-left text direction out of the box, but you'll need to make a couple of adjustments to your markup and Sass to get everything up and running." This is just some minor changes, nothing special.
For bootstrap there's a special version that is focused on RTL support: https://github.com/Kaakati/RTL_Bootstrap

Comment: We welcome any questions or enhancements with regards to RTL/translations etc in the Zurb Foundation theme, so if you use that, feel free to give us feedback in the issue queue.